# How to restrict a user to use his user name only (with which he is authenticated) after he is authenticated using "cloud auth login" in IAP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Once I am authenticated on "Google Cloud SDK Shell" using below command

```
gcloud auth login
```

I can specify any user name before host name and can login to the server:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "santa@suse12" --project "mytower" --tunnel-through-iaps
```

The problem is that if someone pass a incorrect user name because of typo he will still be able to login or someone can use any others users name to login. This will make the environment complex to manage.

Can anyone help me to find the solution to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) could be a solution in this case. It bounds Linux user to Google identity and keeps consistent usernames across Linux instances. In this way the same Linux account is used across all instances in the same project or organization. Access to VM instances can be easily revoked by removing IAM permissions.

You will need the latest version of [guest environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment) installed on Linux instances. Public images provided by Google already have it. If you use custom images, you should [install](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment) it yourself.

OS Login can be enabled at the Organization, Project or Instance level.

For information on setting up OS Login or for step-by-step instructions, see
[Setting up OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)